# Non blocking GUI at EditorCoroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UnityEditor script where I have long running processes (File.ReadAllText() and XMLNode.SelectSingleNode()) that start when a button is clicked. I just want to inform the user to be patient. The problem is that the time consuming processing starts immediately when the button is clicked. The GUI doesn't do a redraw where I can put my message to the user.

I currently solve it for me by simply running a coroutine multiple times to be sure the message is drawn. But that looks cumbersome to me. Does anyone know better?

Thank you awesome people from SO :)

```
int fileProcessingEnumerator = 0;

// called on every redraw of my editor
void OnGUI()
{
  DisplayRunButton();
}

/// <summary>
/// Draw a GUI button and handle the click
/// </summary>
private void DisplayRunButton()
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    if (GUILayout.Button("<<  GO!  >>"))
    {
        fileProcessingEnumerator = 1;
        EditorCoroutineUtility.StartCoroutine(ProcessFiles(), this);
    }
    if (fileProcessingEnumerator > 0)
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Importprocess is running, please be patient..");
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}

/// <summary>
/// Do the import of the files
/// </summary>
private IEnumerator ProcessFiles()
{
    fileProcessingEnumerator++;
    if (fileProcessingEnumerator < 3)
        yield return null;

    apDocument = new ApDocument(File.ReadAllText(apFilePath));
    cDocument = new CDocument(File.ReadAllText(cFilePath));       //very expensive function
    fileProcessingEnumerator = 0;
}
```

Comment: do it in a thread? your coroutine basically only yields once so anyway this will run sync -> freeze ... please post a complete code .. what exactly are you doing with `cDocument` in the end?

Comment: How can it be done in a thread then? I thought EditorCoroutine() is the way to do things asynchronously, like it is done with Coroutine() in GameEngine. But obviously it doesn't work that way in the editor. Because I know that in my current version the editor freezes. My approach up there is for just having another editor redraw to at least print the message for the user. Because waiting for the file reader and CDocument construtor (xml validation) takes a lot of time. All steps after this intial loading and related to CDocument are decoupled from this step and therefore do not block anything.

Comment: A Coroutine is never "asynchronous" it only splits the work over multiple frames but still runs in the one main thread

Comment: Ok. I did not know that. Thanks for that. Your answer with the `ConcurrentQueue` rings a bell ... far away. :)

Answer (score 0):

So as said you should make the loading asynchronous. Note that a Coroutine, in playmode or in the Editor, is **never** asynchronous. All that it allows is to `yield` which basically does

"Pause this routine, render this frame, continue this routine from here in the frame"

Everything between two `yield` statements is still executed in the Unity main thread.

---

Now there are probably many valid ways of how to do that exactly.

One would be to use an `async Task` and a main thread dispatcher pattern. Have to say that I'm not an expert for `async - await` so not totally sure it is done that way or if there is a more elegant solution ;)

```
// These are thread safe queues for handling loaded files back in the Unity thread
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<ApDocument> apDocs = new ConcurrentQueue<ApDocuemnt>(); 
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<cDocument> cDocs = new ConcurrentQueue<cDocuemnt>();

// Check if the routine is running  
private bool busy;

// called on every redraw of my editor
void OnGUI()
{
    DisplayRunButton();
}

/// <summary>
/// Draw a GUI button and handle the click
/// </summary>
private void DisplayRunButton()
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    {
        // Disable the button during the loading
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(busy);
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("<<  GO!  >>"))
            {
                EditorCoroutineUtility.StartCoroutine(ProcessFiles(), this);
            }
        }
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
        if(busy)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Importprocess is running, please be patient..");
        }
    }
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}

private IEnumerator ProcessFilesRoutine()
{
    // Set the busy flag for the drawer
    busy = true;

    // Start the async task
    var loadingTask = Task.Run(ProcessFiles);

    // Wait until the async task is done without freezing
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => loadingTask.IsCompleted);

    // handle the results  
    while(apDocs.TryDequeue(out var apDoc))
    {
        apDocument = apDoc;
    }

    while(cDocs.TryDequeue(out var cDoc))
    {
        cDocument = cDoc;
    }

    // Release the flag
    busy = false;
}

// Do long stuff in a Task using async - await
private async Task ProcessFiles()
{ 
    // Async file reading
    var apContent = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(apFilePath);
    var apDoc = new ApDocument(apContent);
    var cContent = await File.ReadAllText(cFilePath);
    var cDoc = new CDocument();

    // Enqueue the results into the thread safe queuea
    apDocs.Enqueue(apDoc);  
    cDocs.Enqueu(cDoc);     
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*